# Не работает привязка Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

Не применяется стиль в элементам ListBox, то есть если просто указать значения в стиле работает, а если установить привязку, то нет. Сами элементы для привязки содержат корректную информацию и если их привязать просто к другому элементу, все будет работать, но с ListBox не работает.

```
<Style x:Key="WrapStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding ConfigWindowModels.ServicesTextFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{Binding ConfigWindowModels.ServicesTextFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ConfigWindowModels.ServicesForeGroundText}" />
    <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
</Style>






        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Width="35" Source="/Resources/check.png" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <TextBlock Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Text="" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="13"/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource WrapStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent"   ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  BorderThickness="0"  ItemsSource="{Binding ListCollectionSecond}" Visibility="{Binding VisibleList}" SelectedItem="{Binding ListCollectionSelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DoubleClick}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение. В итоге для того чтобы привязать характеристику к ListBoxItem, необходимо чтобы параметр передавался в объекте который привязан к Itemsource ListBox.

Пример:

```
public ObservableCollection<testSource> ss { get; set; }
public class testSource
{
    public string s1 { get; set; }
    public string color
    {
        get
        {
            return "red";
        }
    }
}


public Class1()
{
    ss = new ObservableCollection<testSource>();
    ss.Add(new testSource { s1 = "1"});
    ss.Add(new testSource { s1 = "1"});
    ss.Add(new testSource { s1 = "1"});
    ss.Add(new testSource { s1 = "1"});


}


<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="testData">
        <Grid >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Width="35" Source="/back.png" Grid.Row="1"/>
                <TextBlock Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Text="" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="13"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource tbTrim}"  Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding s1}" Grid.Column="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="tbTrim">
        <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding color}"/>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource testData}"  ItemsSource="{Binding ss}">

    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```